# dc.js - How do I add Totals to a dataTable?

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter, dc.js

Suppose I have a datatable created in dc.js that looks like:

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║ Name       ║ Amount      ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ Bob        ║ 25          ║
║ 2 ║ Sam        ║ 25          ║
║ 3 ║ Steve      ║ 50          ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

How do I create a subtotal at the bottom?

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║ Name       ║ Amount      ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ Bob        ║ 25          ║
║ 2 ║ Sam        ║ 25          ║
║ 3 ║ Steve      ║ 50          ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╝
  Total is equal to 100
════════════════════════════════
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**Ans:**
I ended up adding the following code to the datatable to make it work.

```
.renderlet(function (d) { return UpdateSummary(d); });
```

Inside the function "UpdateSummary" is where I updated the text "Total is equal to 100"

Comment: Would you care to add a jsFiddle to illustrate your solution? Although I'm about to roll my own right now, it would be nice to have a head start available. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you share the code, I might be able to help more specifically. Here's my advice in the meantime.

dc.js uses crossfilter groups to set the data for tables. Whichever group you set to this table (in the `.group()` method) say

```
var helperArray = myGroup.all(),
total = 0;

helperArray.forEach(function(d) {total += d.value.amount;}) 
// console.log(d) to see what d is. it might need to just be total+= d.value

d3.select("body").append("p") //this should be changed to make it the right spot
    .text("Total is equal to " + total)
```

Something to that effect.

Comment: Not sure if valid, but the docs say "data table does not use crossfilter group but rather a closure as a grouping function".

Comment: Is there any custom d3 code that will display aggregated numbers iin the data table???